# How do I bulk_delete in django?

Tags: django-views, django-templates

I need to delete select items by a checkbox and delete all the so selected items.
I tried this but it doesn't work.
I have tried other similar questions but couldn't get help

```
<table class="layout container">
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Mark</th>
    </thead>
  {% for book in books %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ book.book_name }}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="marked_delete" value="{{ book.pk }}" {% if '{{ book.pk }}' in 'marked_delete' %} checked {% endif %}>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The view

```
def delete_bulk_books(request):
    book = request.GET.get('marked_delete')
    books = Books.objects.filter(id__in=marked_delete).delete()
    return redirect("view_books")
```

Comment: And this remains???? <input type="checkbox" name="marked_delete" value="{{ book.pk }}" {% if '{{ book.pk }}' in 'marked_delete' %} checked {% endif %}>

Comment: how exactly do you submit the form? There does not seems to be a `<form>` included in your template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`getlist(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist), instead of <s>`.get('marked_delete')`</s>:

```
def delete_bulk_books(request):
    book = request.GET.getlist('marked_delete')
    books = Books.objects.filter(id__in=marked_delete).delete()
    return redirect('view_books')
```

Normally however requests that have *delete* are done through a POST or DELETE request, you thus might want to work with a form that makes a POST request.

Comment: I have this at the top of my page. <a class='text-right' href="{% url 'marked_delete' %}">Delete Selected</a>

Comment: @fakeMake: that will not make any request with the data in the checkboxes, you need to work with a `<form method="post" action="{% url 'marked_delete' %}">` and submit the form, then you can work with `request.POST.getlist('marked_delete')` A GET request is *not* supposed to create/update/delete any items, since a GET request only *retrieves* data.

Comment: Let me have a form for this... Thanks a lot and I'll get back...